# How can I count all zeros before the first non-zero number

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

This is the issue here:

```
echo -0.00092711066827 | grep -o 0

0
0
0
0
0

echo -0.00092711066827 | grep -o 0 | wc -l

5
```

but I need to count all zeros before the first, non-zero number, in this case all zeros before the number 9 (e.g., 4 zeros). It'd be great also to know how to count all this 4 zeros plus the first non-zero integer (in this case it would be 4 zeros plus the 9).

Hints are welcomed,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do like this,

```
$ echo -0.00092711066827 | grep -o '^[^1-9]\+' | grep -o '0' | wc -l
4
```

Answer (score 2):

With bash:

```
x='-0.00092711066827'
[[ $x =~ ([0.]+).* ]]
y="${BASH_REMATCH[1]//./}"
echo "${#y}"
```

Output:

```
4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ printf '%e\n' -0.00092711066827 | sed 's/^.\+e-//'
04
```

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, I got `bash: printf: -0.00092711066827: invalid number
0,000000e+00`

Comment: Then tell `printf` to use a locale that uses a period as the radix point. `LC_NUMERIC=en_US printf ...`

Answer (score 1):

Two shell solutions (no external program):

```
s="-0.00092711066827"

a="${s%%[1-9]*}" ;                 # cut at the first non-zero digit.
a="${a//[^0]/}";                   # remove all non-zero characters.
echo "${#a}"                       # print the count of zeros.

b="$(LC_ALL=C printf '%e' "$s")"   # convert to Scientific notation.
echo "$((${b##*e-}+0))"            # convert exponent to number.
```